# altinstall error

Tags: python, make

Hello I have just install python as highlighted below there is an error for altinstall, should I use make install?

```
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make altinstall
```

or

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I was following a tutorial and this was the error.

```
File "/home/plutes/Downloads/Python-3.6.6rc1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/home/plutes/Downloads/Python-3.6.6rc1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal
**zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
Makefile:1113: recipe for target 'altinstall' failed
make: *** [altinstall] Error 1**

plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~/Downloads/Python-3.6.6rc1$ cd

plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ python
python             python3            python3.6m-config  python3m
python2            python3.6          python3.7          
python2.7          python3.6m         python3.7m         
plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ python3.6

Python 3.6.6rc1 (default, Jun 17 2018, 21:36:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 3.6's help utility!

as you can see it works, but I am unsure about future uses. thanks for any guidance.

plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ python3.6
Python 3.6.6rc1 (default, Jun 17 2018, 21:36:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("Hello, World!")  
Hello, World!
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

I've just experienced the same issue with installing `python3.7.3` on `ubuntu18.04`.
Following [this message](https://bugs.python.org/msg321260) and running:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev \
zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev \
libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev
```

Allowed me to successfully run `sudo make altinstall`.

Comment: Would you update the web link?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the new link is, might be this: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75833#issuecomment-1093760728

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Ubuntu and the two top answers did not work. I used the answer I got from https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/common-build-problems and tried again and it worked. basically I did:

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \
xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git
```

and then:

```
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: This did it for me on Ubuntu 22.04 aarch64. However, I had to repeat the build process like in [desertSniper87s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081667/1112787)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands in this order:

1. `./configure`
2. `make clean`
3. `make`
4. `sudo make install`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody reads this thread, the issue is actually that a dependency is missing. In this case, zlib headers.

Basically, you must:

1.- Enable the deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/.

```
 echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

2.- `sudo apt update`

3.- Install python deps

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.6
```

Now you can run `make altinstall`

You can read more details at https://bugs.python.org/issue36135.

Answer (score 0):

Installing following dependencies will solve the issue:

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev
libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```